# C# wordprocessing XML replace picture

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a docx document where I inserted a "blank" grey .jpg image named "imgholder".

Here is the XML data opening in Notepad:

```
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
</w:rPr>
<w:pict w14:anchorId="01AD6CAE">
<v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
<v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
<v:formulas>
<v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
</v:formulas>
<v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
<o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:shapetype>
<v:shape id="_x0000_s2051" type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute;margin-left:355pt;margin-top:-.1pt;width:70.85pt;height:70.85pt;z-index:2;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-relative:page;mso-height-relative:page">
<v:imagedata r:id="rId6" o:title="imgholder"/>
</v:shape>
</w:pict>
</w:r>
```

What I have managed to do is to:

- get all pictures in the doc
- generate a qr code
- convert to data
- replace data with the existing image data. (eg below: imp[1])

  ```
        //get all images
        List<ImagePart> imp = mainDocumentPart.ImageParts.ToList();

        //generate qr code
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("This is a QR code.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
        Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);

        //convert bitmap to byte
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(qrCodeImage, typeof(byte[]));

        //replace image inserting the new byte data
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(imp[1].GetStream());
        writer.Write(imageBytes);
        writer.Close();
  ```

This actually replaces the image with the QR code just fine.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the image by ID and replace that.
I am trying to do something to get id from this line
<v:imagedata r:id="rId6" o:title="imgholder"/>
an replace that image with the qr data.

However, all the documentation I found for XML is how to add new image and replace 1 with Drawing, Blip, etc.
My document for Drawing comes back with 0 result so that is no the way to go.

```
        List<Drawing> draw = mainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Drawing>().ToList();
        Debug.WriteLine("Drawing = " + draw.Count());
        //get all images
        List<ImagePart> imp = mainDocumentPart.ImageParts.ToList();
        Debug.WriteLine("ImagePart = " + imp.Count());
```

Drawing = 0
ImagePart = 4

Any idea how to find the Imagedata by ID or Name or Title (I actually know this) and find the related ImagePart? (I do not know this)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved it.

I went through the XML first and got all "ImageData".

```
List<ImageData> imgdat = mainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<ImageData>().ToList();
```

then got all ImageData with "Title" = "imgholder" and returned the "RelationshipId"

```
foreach (var imgd in imgdat)
            {
                if (imgd.Title.Equals("qrholder"))
                {
                    imgID = imgd.RelationshipId;
                }
            }
```

Then I used that ID to find the "ImagePart" using GetPartById

```
ImagePart imagePart = (ImagePart)document.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(imgID);
```